# Storing the POST array in mysql without empty values?

Tags: php, arrays, post, filter

Here's one that has me stumped.

I am storing the $_POST array in a mysql database. I am using JavaScript to dynamically create input fields on my form too but if an input field is empty is still gets inserted into the database (obviously).

Is there anyway to go through the POST array and filter these empty values out?

**EDIT:**

Using WordPress but same idea:

```
<?php 
foreach($_POST['eirepanel_inline_ads_options_name'] as $post_eirepanel_inline_ads_options_name):
    if(empty($post_eirepanel_inline_ads_options_name)): 
       echo 'empty';
    else: 
        update_option('eirepanel_inline_ads_options', $_POST);
        $eirepanel_inline_ads_options = get_option('eirepanel_inline_ads_options');
    endif; 
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: How do you deal with submit button values? What do you consider an empty value? Empty string? 0?

Comment: Submit values have a boolean value. An empty value would be an empty string

Comment: Hmm, what is the text displayed on the submit-button?

Comment: Are you making use of arrays in your form ([PHP arrays via form-field names](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays))?

Answer (score 2):

You said that you only want the elements of the $_POST array that are not an empty string:

```
   $nonEmpty = array_filter($_POST, function($value) {return $value!=='';} );
```

You wrote you add fields dynamically. I don't know if you make use of the [PHP notation for arrays in form fields](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays). If so things do get a little more different to deal with that additional type of data.

Answer (score 1):

There are several.  However, beware of controls that don't always send values.  You won't necessarily get a value for a checkbox if it's not ticked.

Since you're using Javascript, how about you store the form as JSON:

```
<?php
$formVars = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
   if ($value != ''){
      $formVars[$key] = $value;
   }
}

$form = json_encode($formVars);//Store this in DB
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the $_POST before inserting anything in the database

```
if($_POST['email'] == "") { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that :

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if (empty($value))
    {
        unset($_POST[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do an empty check on it.

**DISCLAIMER**
This is a simple example. Does not check whether `$value` is an array (e.g. checkbox or file input). Works only for inputs.

```
$data = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
   if (empty($value)) continue;
   $data[$key] = $value;
}
//save $data to DB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter_post($value)
{ 
  if ($value !='')
  {
    return $value;
  }

}
$new_array=array_filter($_POST,'filter_post');
```